# Como abrir 4 Selects sequenciais, sendo os 2 últimos não relacionados a ítens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

**EDITADO**

Tenho 4 selects que chamei de Nível:

O Nível 1 abre o Nível 2 conforme cada item é selecionado.

Cada item do Nível 1 abre um select específico (funciona e usa Jquery)

**O que preciso:**

Qdo selecionar **qualquer item do Nível 2**, Abra o único select Nível 3.

E qdo selecionar **qualquer item do Nível 3**, Abra o select Nível 4

**obs:** Não há relação entre ítens, apenas abrir o nível 3 e 4

E como esconder os níveis 2, 3 e 4? Mostrar só qdo o anterior for selecionado. (por exemplo: Qdo o usuario entra pela 1ª vez só mostra o Nível 1 > seleciona > mostra Nível 2 > seleciona > mostra Nível 3 > seleciona > mostra Nível 4)

Agradeço os alertas e me desculpem.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.hidden').hide();
 //Roda OK = nível 1 abre nível 2 
 $('select[name=nivel1]').change(function(){
  var id = $('select[name=nivel1]').val();
  $('select[name=nivel2]').empty();
  $('select[name=nivel2]').html($('div.nivel2-f' + id).html());
 });
  
 //tentei este. Não faz nada - Como fazer??
 $('select[name=nivel2]').change(function(){
  var id = $('select[name=nivel2]').val();
  $('select[name=nivel3]').empty();
  $('select[name=nivel3]').html($('div.nivel3-f' + id).html());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select name='nivel1' required>
 <option value='0'>Selecionar Nivel 1</option>
 <option value='1'>texto A</option>
 <option value='2'>texto B</option>
</select>
<select name='nivel2'></select>
<div class="hidden nivel2-f1">
 <option value='3'>A texto a</option>
 <option value='4'>A texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel2-f2">
 <option value='5'>B texto a</option>
 <option value='6'>B texto b</option>
</div>
<!-- até aqui esta OK = Nível 1 abre Nivel 2 -->

<!-- aqui começa Nível 3 e Nivel 4 (incompleto)-->
<select name='nivel3'></select>
<div class="hidden nivel3-f3">
 <option value='7'>AAA</option>
 <option value='8'>BBB</option>
</div>
<select name='nivel4'></select>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f4">
 <option value='9'>DDD</option>
 <option value='10'>EEE</option>
</div>
<button type="submit">Gravar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: como vc não montou um exemplo funcional não da pra saber bem o que vc quer fazer, pode explicar melhor? de qualquer forma, não deve colocar elementos `div` dentro dos `options`, deve sempre ser um `select`, os `options` e fechar o select, igual ao que fez no "nivel1"

Comment: Se abrir o Executar veras que o exemplo funciona no nível 1. Eu quero que qdo selecionar o Nível 2 Abra o Nível 3. E qdo selecionar o Nível 3 Abra o Nível 4. O original de 2 níveis com as Divs foi obtido de um site com exemplos Jquery (faz algum tempo). Mas se vc tem um exemplo diferente de 4 níveis sequenciais, poderia mostrar aqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema.

O passo inicial para compreensão do problema foi melhor a endentação. Havia uma tentativa de aninhar estruturas não relacionada e isso dificultava a leitura do código. Resolvido esse problema eu consegui compreender do que se tratava o problema.

O autor da pergunta gostaria de encadear o conteúdo de uma série de `<selects>`, quatro no total, onde o conteúdo dum `<select>` dependesse do anterior.

### O que eu fiz?

Eu apenas progredi o pensamento já existente mantendo um incremento unitário e constante para `<option value>`. Fiz com que o evento `change` propagasse para o próximo  assim quando se alterasse um os subsequentes teriam seus conteúdos acomodados.

```js
$(function(){

    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('select[name=nivel1]').change(function(){

     var id = $('select[name=nivel1]').val();
        $('select[name=nivel2],select[name=nivel3],select[name=nivel4] ').prop("disabled", id === 0 );

        $('select[name=nivel2]').empty();
        $('select[name=nivel3]').empty();
        $('select[name=nivel4]').empty();

        $('select[name=nivel2]').html($('div.nivel2-f' + id).html());
        $('select[name=nivel2]').change();    

    });
  
    $('select[name=nivel2]').change(function(){
        var id = $('select[name=nivel2]').val();
        $('select[name=nivel3]').empty();
        $('select[name=nivel4]').empty();
        $('select[name=nivel3]').html($('div.nivel3-f' + id).html());
        $('select[name=nivel3]').change();
    });

    $('select[name=nivel3]').change(function(){
        var id = $('select[name=nivel3]').val();
        $('select[name=nivel4]').empty();
        $('select[name=nivel4]').html($('div.nivel4-f' + id).html());
        $('select[name=nivel4]').change();
    });    
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select name='nivel1' required>
 <option value='0'>Selecionar Nivel 1</option>
 <option value='1'>texto A</option>
 <option value='2'>texto B</option>
</select><br><br>
<select name='nivel2' disabled="true"></select>
<div class="hidden nivel2-f1">
 <option value='3'>A texto a</option>
 <option value='4'>A texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel2-f2">
 <option value='5'>B texto a</option>
 <option value='6'>B texto b</option>
</div><br><br>
<!-- até aqui esta OK = Nível 1 abre Nivel 2 -->

<!-- aqui começa Nível 3 e Nivel 4 (incompleto)-->
<select name='nivel3' disabled="disabled"></select>
<div class="hidden nivel3-f3">
 <option value='7'>Aa texto a</option>
 <option value='8'>Aa texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel3-f4">
 <option value='9'>Ab texto a</option>
 <option value='10'>Ab texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel3-f5">
 <option value='11'>Ba texto a</option>
 <option value='12'>Ba texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel3-f6">
 <option value='13'>Bb texto a</option>
 <option value='14'>Bb texto b</option>
</div><br><br>

<select name='nivel4' disabled="disabled"></select>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f7">
 <option value='11'>Aaa texto a</option>
 <option value='12'>Aaa texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f8">
 <option value='13'>Aab texto a</option>
 <option value='14'>Aab texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f9">
 <option value='11'>Aba texto a</option>
 <option value='12'>Aba texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f10">
 <option value='13'>Abb texto a</option>
 <option value='14'>Abb texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f11">
 <option value='11'>Baa texto a</option>
 <option value='12'>Baa texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f12">
 <option value='13'>Bab texto a</option>
 <option value='14'>Bab texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f13">
 <option value='11'>Aaa texto a</option>
 <option value='12'>Aaa texto b</option>
</div>
<div class="hidden nivel4-f14">
 <option value='13'>Bba texto a</option>
 <option value='14'>Bbb texto b</option>
</div><br><br>
<button type="submit">Gravar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: É isto mesmo. E como esconder os níveis 2,3,4 qdo entra pela 1ª vez? Agradeço antecipadamente sua grande ajuda.

Comment: Você pode usar a propriedade `disabled="true"` para desabilitar os `<selects>` para que só possam ser selecionados caso o primeiro `<select>` tiver o valor adequado. De uma olhada no exemplo.

Comment: só comento a mesma coisa da pergunta: usar um <div> entre o <select> e o <option> é uma gambiarra que sai fora da semântica da estrutura do <select>, assim como seria com <table><tr><td> e <ul><li>  por exemplo. Embora isso responda a pergunta, é interessante orientar sobre isso.

Comment: @RicardoPontual concordo com você. Eu pessoalmente havia me disposto a refatorar o código para algo mais dinâmico, mas to no meio do expediente e optei por dar continuidade ao exemplo da pergunta.  A noite eu faço as considerações e a clarificação. Obrigado pelo comentário.